# Generate a boxplot in Gnupot using a a particular representation of data

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I'm trying to generate a boxplot with gnuplot using the following data:

```
"Data1"
0.08
0.09
0.1

"Data2"
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0
1.0

"Data3"
0.24
```

Is there a way to generate a boxplot for each Data1 Data2 Data3, represented in this way?

Comment: Do you mean a boxplot like this? http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/boxplot.html In gnuplot, have you checked `help boxplot`?